# Solution to Laplace-like equation $\Delta w+\beta^2w_{zz}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the following PDE:

$$\Delta(\Delta f) + \beta^2 (\Delta f)_{zz}=0$$

Where $\beta$ is a real number, $\Delta$ the Laplacian operator and $f$ is a function with axisymmetry defined outside of a sphere of radius $R$, so in spherical coordinates it only depends on the radial coordinate $r\geq R$ and the polar angle $\theta$. $f_z$ is the partial derivative with respect to the usual $z$ coordinate, or, in terms of the spherical variables:

$$f_z=\cos\theta \,f_r-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}f_{\theta}$$

The boundary conditions are $f(R,\theta)=0$, $f_{r}(R,\theta)=0$ and $f(r\rightarrow\infty,\theta)\rightarrow r\cos\theta$. I tried to obtain a solution with the form $f=f_1+f_2$, where each term satisfies:

$$\Delta f_1=0$$ and
$$\Delta f_2=w,\quad\text{with}\quad\Delta w+\beta^2 w_{zz}=0$$

The equation for $w$ in terms of derivatives with respect to spherical coordinates is:

$$\Delta w+\beta^2\left(\cos^2\theta\,\, w_{rr}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{r}w_{r}+\frac{sin^2\theta}{r^2}w_{\theta\theta}+\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r^2}w_{\theta}-\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r}w_{r\theta}\right)=0$$

I think I found a solution, given by:

$$w=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[c_{n}r^n(1+\beta^2\sin^2\theta)^{n/2}+\frac{k_n}{r^{n+1}(1+\beta^2\sin^2\theta)^{(n+1)/2}}\right]P_n(\zeta)$$

Where $P_n(x)$ is a Legendre polynomial, $\zeta=\cos\theta\,/(1+\beta^2\sin^2\theta)^{1/2}$ and $c_n$ and $k_n$ are constants. Then, I apply the eigenfunction expansion method to get $f_2$, expanding the angular part of $w$ in terms of Legendre polynomial $P_n(\cos\theta)$. But to satisfy the boundary conditions, the coefficients $c_n$ and $k_n$ must follow a relation given by an infinite sum of all of them, so I cannot get an explicit expression for these coefficients.

My questions are, ¿is there a simpler approach to this problem? ¿Should I try to look for another solution $w$?

Comment: Why not define $g = \Delta f$, solve the ODE $$g + \beta^{2} g_{zz} = 0$$ in $g$ and then solve the inhomogeneous PDE $\Delta f = g$?

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing Laplacian operator in the main equation for $f$, I have edited it.